# Git - Error invalid path

Tags: windows, mac, git

I have been working for so long on a mac and have committed it looks like a file like this:

```
C:/Csmart/files/companies/19/migration/CompanyDataEntry.xls
```

This file does not exist in the repository. My repository was actually located in `/Users/Sethuram/Development/Csmart/workspaces/csmart`. It looks like I might have somehow checked in a file with the name `C:/Csmart/files/companies/19/migration/CompanyDataEntry.xls` into my git repo and pushed it.

Now I am trying to clone this repo on my windows box and I get an error like below:

```
error: Invalid path 'C:/Csmart/files/companies/19/migration/CompanyDataEntry.xls'
```

I understand its an invalid path. I am not sure how to correct it. I dont have access to my mac anymore to delete and push from there.

On the windows box this file appears as a change I need to commit:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    C:/Csmart/files/companies/19/migration/CompanyDataEntry.xls
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: There is a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772908/crawling-github-with-jgit

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the file to another path, such as to the current directory

```
git checkout -- <path>/<file>
```

In your case, it should be

```
git checkout -- C:/Csmart/files/companies/19/migration/CompanyDataEntry.xls
```

You can also specify a directory to extract your file

```
git checkout-index --prefix=destination/path/ C:/Csmart/files/companies/19/migration/CompanyDataEntry.xls
```

If that does not help, just export all files into a new directory

```
$ git checkout-index --prefix=git-export-dir/ -a
```

For more information , refer to the documentation for [git checkout-index](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index.html)